# YouTube Data API v3 without leaking access token

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, google-api, youtube-api

I’m working on a web service where users can log in and upload videos to my YouTube channel. I’m OK with the risk of having unapproved content as long as I know who uploaded what. Moreover, I would like to avoid handling file uploads on my own servers.

I started with building a simple proof of concept on top of the YouTube Data API v3. Using OAuth, I obtained a refresh_token for my account. Every time user visits my service I make sure I have a valid access_token with upload permissions (I can generate one from a refresh_token). Because I don’t want to handle file uploads, I used code from https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript to build a JavaScript uploader. It needs an access_token to operate correctly, so JS gets one from the backend via an ajax call.

Now, the problem is that I can’t be sure who uploaded what. One of the users can take the token from his browser and initiate many video uploads out of my site (and my control). I won’t know who did that. I was thinking about generating a separate token for each user, but it seems that there is no way of knowing which access token was used to upload a specific video.

Is there a way to determine who uploaded what without handling file uploads on my end? Maybe something similar to AWS request signing, but for YT Data API? I went through the docs, but couldn’t find anything.

To put it in a different way: is there a way to hide access_token from the user, but still have a JavaScript based uploader that goes directly to YouTube?

Alternatively, I could send those files to S3 (where I can sign requests and know who uploaded what) and have a background job that would transfer those videos to youtube. This, however, is a slow and costly process.

Comment: This isn't really how oAuth works -- what you're seeing is one of the main reasons that YouTube's oAuth flow is designed to prevent you from having lots of users upload videos into a single account (and why YouTube doesn't work with service accounts). The "signing" is represented by the fact that, with oAuth, they ostensibly should be logging into their own account rather than yours ... that's where the identification comes in. You'll have to either upload to S3 first as you suggest, upload to your own server, or have users upload into their own accounts.